# Display Locations on UITableview

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview

[image]I want to display the locations in `UITableView`. Here I take one `UITextField` and `UITableView`. Now I want to display the name of location in the table view according to the keyword typed in the text field. Any one know how to do that? Please help me friends.  The table view should bring up suggested places because sometimes user might misspell the city name or there might be the same city name in different country.

on bases of above image You can understand what exactly i need.

Comment: Can you be a bit clearer in what you are trying to achieve? Also, some code showing what you have tried so far would help people help you.

Comment: i too am pondering on how to do this... you mean like with a table view it brings up suggested places because sometimes you might misspell the city name or their might be same city name in different country right...

Comment: @user1260708 ya u r Right do You Know How To do That

Comment: I tried to clean it up a bit, but it still might need more clarification.

Comment: @PeterDeWeese which kind of clarification i am ready to give it.

Comment: For a start, what have you tried so far?

Comment: i get the address like if i type "san" than i am getting "san diego,Usa" and i am also successful in displaying this addresses in table view also but if i press backspace than it does't reflect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is [geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/). You can fairly easily integrate calls to Google's Geocoding API in your app - simply take the user input from the UITextField, send it in a request to Google, and parse the data that you get back to populate the data source for your UITableView. Google will even provide multiple suggestions in their response if there are multiple places that could match your query.

Comment: can i use uisearch bar to get input from user?

Comment: Yes - just implement the [UISearchBarDelegate protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) to receive notification of text changes in your search bar.

Comment: Can u give me the link of any example or any tutorial like this if u have it than plz help me out.

Comment: [Google is your friend](http://blog.sallarp.com/ipad-iphone-forward-geocoding-api-google/).