# Displaying suggested locations in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview, uisearchbar

Basically what I want to do in my app is have a `UISearchBar` which, when I write in, will feedback location results and populate that into a UITableView that appears. I see one more question on this site:

[Display Locations on UITableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10140536/display-locations-on-uitableview)

But that really didn't help me, no answer helped me at all, and they were quite vague.

So, my question is. You know how some apps maybe you have to type in a city or country, but the user might not be able to fully spell it, so based on your `UISearchBar` results, it presents a TableView with the suggested cities. So say I am about to write Singapore, I don't know how it is spelled. So I write:

'Sing'

And BAM, a UITableView below pops up with different options/cell titles, including a cell that suggests 'Singapore'. Then I click on that cell and then my search bar is autofilled with 'Singapore'. Here is a screenshot example of what I want to do with a current app called 'iChangi' on the Singapore app store:

[image: Screenshot of what I am trying to do]

So I understand I should implement the `UISearchBar` delegate where the text changed, but what I want to know is there an API or database I can query to feedback the suggested cities? And **how** would I go around doing this, can you provide me with a tutorial on it or simply state a few steps.

Comment: I think the downvote is because it's not clear what you are asking. Why is displaying locations any different to displaying any other data? What problem do you actually have? Asking for "personal thoughts" is begging for a "not constructive" close vote. An answer consisting of tutorial links is not a good fit for SO ( link only answers may not be useful in a years time).

Comment: OK ill rephrase my question... then come back to see if you can help me ;)

Comment: It's a much better question now! I don't know the answer, but I've given you an upvote :)

Comment: oh ok thanks!!!!! Man, I really need an answer to this!!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this project http://iosboilerplate.com/#maps

Comment: Hmmm... I have tried moving over that code to my computer but it seems to fail to build because it cant find the implementation for JSONDecoder which is in the JSONKit which I have clearly imported

Comment: it is referenced in the AFJSONRequestOperation class

Comment: Check if JSONKit it's added in Build Phases -> Compile Sources.

Comment: Note: this project uses a deprecated Google API. If you want to use this project you'll need to convert it to use the [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete)

Answer (score 5):

With the Help of Table view and search bar you can create presentation of City list. Now about API for city list there is many link availibale on Map for same. Please refer below

http://www.geonames.org/export/

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/cities_world

Download Table from above URL and place this with resource directory and use this for suggestion.

See more link for same

http://www.geodatasource.com/cities-free.html

http://weather.noaa.gov/data/nsd_cccc.txt

http://www.geonames.org/export/JSON-webservices.html#citiesJSON

Comment: but can you please provide a bit more detailed explanation on the API, I am quite a beginner at that.... thanks!

Comment: Please refer Left hand side of Google API, there is a list of items. Started API and all. Read this document, and create credential for the same.

Comment: Or simaply download City table xls and use this file for suggestion. If you have server side implementation in your app then ask server side developer for City list. It would be easy on server.

Comment: See my Updated ans, may it help you

Comment: thank you ill try it out! Also, I will give you the +50 only when the bounty ends...

Comment: https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/cities_world.csv
Link looks interesting, with a full list of the cities, how would I go around implementing that, sorry if I am asking too many questions, it is just that this is a pretty new topic to me

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11522/discussion-between-mangesh-vyas-and-rohan-kapur)

Answer (score 2):

I know it's quite late, but maybe it can help others,
I've recently created `autocomplete view`, which can be attached to any `UITextField`, with single line of code. Colors, separators, margins can be configured. Ships with google locations completion source.

You can [clone it from GitHub](https://github.com/TarasRoshko/TRAutocompleteView)

Comment: Hey, thats really cool. However, I've moved on from these days :)