# How to create a location autocompletion input field in iOS 5?

Tags: ios, mapkit, geocoding, reverse-geocoding, mkreversegeocoder

I know iOS offers `MKReverseGeocoder` which translates the user's lat/long into a location like "San Francisco", but is there also the opposite? To create a text field where users type "San F" and it offers locations starting with "San F" to choose from?

Which services are available to return locations and lat/long for a given city name substring search?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Displaying suggested locations in UITableView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10661707/displaying-suggested-locations-in-uitableview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Places has a new [Autocomplete API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/autocomplete)